# Is there a keyboard shortcut for locating the current file in Project Navigator?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to easily get the current file in the Editor pane selected in the Project Navigator without the need to expand all folders (if the file is buried deep down somewhere)?

I know you can see the location in your project using the "bread crumb" on top op the Editor pane, but I like a functionality similar to the one in Visual Studio...

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Right click and choose `Reveal in Project Navigator` (may be under `Navigate` sub menu), or press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

See [Xcode 4 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html) for more, or better yet, use [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/).

Comment: Don't know when this was added, but the `Reveal in Project Navigator` command is now available in the `Navigate` menu as well (if, for example, a Property List is open and the option isn't available in the menu for right click). Keyboard shortcut is identical

Comment: Is there as well a setting to just always show the current file in the project navigator? I don't understand why this isn't the default...