# Copy file full path in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm using Perforce for managing our code base. In Perforce, we need to check out a file before we can edit it. When I'm working in Xcode, sometimes I want to know the full path to the working file so that I can check it out in Perforce.

So here is my question:

Is there a **shortcut**, **plugin** or some other quick way to copy the full path of a file in **Xcode**?

What I have known:

1. I can `Command+click` on the file tile to show up the full path, but I cannot copy it.
2. In **Visual Studio**, we can right click on the file's tab and choose `Copy Full Path` to achieve this.
3. In **Eclipse**, we can `Alt/Option + Enter` to achieve this.

**Update:**

Actually my question is about how to achieve the equivalent `Copy Full Path` feature **inside Xcode**. Anyway, dragging the file to the terminal is also a very nice workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy it directly out of the File Inspector. The first section ("Identity and Type") of the File Inspector shows information about the selected file, or the file that contains the selected symbol, etc. You have *Name*, *Type*, *Location*, and *Full Path*. You can select the full path and copy it.

As a shortcut, a triple click on any part of the path will select the entire path. There's also a small icon with a light arrow on a dark background -- clicking that will open a Finder window with the file selected.

Comment: Actually I like your solution better, since I want to copy the full path inside Xcode and I believe Xcode should provide this feature:) Dragging a file to the terminal is also very cool but it seems a little bit like a workaround:)

Answer (score 7):

You can drag it to a terminal... Easy and fast...

Comment: I got used to drag-n-dropping file to the open editor.

Answer (score 4):

Extending [Caleb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404129/3148856), here is a graphical demo:
Steps:

1. Select a filename on the **Project navigator** from the left side **Navigator** panel.
2. Tap on **Show File Inspector** from the right side **Inspectors** panel. (marked with red box)
3. Copy the path from there. (marked with a bigger red box)

[image: Screenshot of Xcode showing how to copy full file path]

Comment: Great answer. For anyone else thinking "But my current active file isn't highlighted in the Project Navigator on the left", [here's how to jump to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801279/568458)

Answer (score 1):

on your editor XCode (you want to get the file path). Press:

```
Command+Shift+J
```

xcode will open directory file path on Project Navigator (left side bar)

and then drag-and-drop file from Project Navigator to the terminal. it will give you the directory of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command to copy file path:

```
cd myProject
find . -name myCodeFile.cpp
```